# What is the best way for SMS verification using API and PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, api

I am building a website where users enter their phone numbers and *OTP(one-time password)* is sent to their mobile phones. I am using an API service that sends messages to customer's mobile phone but it doesn't create a one-time password and it doesn't have a system for verifications. So I will do this instead and create a 6-digit password and put it inside of the message. But my question is how can I verify if the customer enters the correct password?

**One way to do this is:**
to save that password in the database and check if the customer entered matching passwords. But in this case, I don't know where to store this password inside the database. Should I create a table for password verifications? If so, I also need to create a *gsm number* column for checking passwords which means I need to hold customers' gsm numbers somewhere but I don't think it is necessary. There should be a way to verify passwords without needing the customer's mobile phone number. (As far as I know)

Another way is to store OTP in the cookie and after the customer enters the password I can check using the password inside the cookie but I think it is not a safe way since there is a way to reach cookies' values in user interface.

I guess I can use trigger and/or stored procedures for this issue but still I have no idea.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not use client-side storage (cookie) to verify client-side input (password). It's not secure at all. Use server to verify password.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/one-time-passcode-verification-otp

Comment: Yeah, I won't use this logic. But still, I have no idea how to use the database and server to verify the password. @Jax-p

Comment: There are tried and true TOTP/OTP/HTOP libraries out there that I'd encourage you to look into. You generally give a user a single key, one time, which can be used to generate many codes that are valid for a certain period. The library will show you how to verify the provided code against the user's key

Comment: My company uses an API service from another company. I should use that API service. @ChrisHaas

Comment: If that API service is what generates the OTP, I'd treat the OTP similar to a password and store it hashed alongside the user. Verification is the same for password then. However if the API generates the OTP, I'd also assume that it can verify it?

Comment: This API service provides only sending messages to the customers' mobile phones. @ChrisHaas. I am the one who needs to handle verification logic.

Comment: What I'm saying is to use a library to generate and verify those code. You can continue to use the service for sending them. But otherwise I'd just treat them like a password like I said. Unless you want to support expiration, that's another feature common to OTP and built into most libraries.

Comment: I agree with you @ChrisHaas. What you suggest is the best way since it is safe and secure to use a library yet I need to build this system on my own to learn. That's why I need the StackOverflow community's help.

Comment: `"I also need to create a gsm number column for checking passwords which means I need to hold customers' gsm numbers somewhere"` . No, the user should provide their number, and you should be able to compare this number to one you have on file for that user. The number on file should be hashed (just like a password) and so the data is safe. The user enters their number, and if the pwd hashes match, that's ok and THEN you can send the data to the number value they gave you. Therefore you never need to store the unhashed phone number outside of server memory (however, it might be in logs etc.).

Comment: You should be aware that SMS communications have absolutely **NO AUTHENTICATION SECURITY** at all, and **ANYONE** can read SMS; you can even download things from Amazon that can intercept SMS communications. SMS is **NOT A SECURE WAY OF COMMUNICATING**. It's even worse than email which is an achievement. You should instead be looking at using some form of online messenger system such as **Signal Messeger** for authenticating someone's phone number. or better yet **using a proper 2FA system**.

Comment: Use a proper TOTP library to generate codes from an initial key (which you generate randomly). You need to store the inital key for the OTP in the database. Do not send this to the client, just generate a code, then ask the client to enter the code using another method. You can verify the code using the standard TOTP verification methods

Comment: Thank you guys, those are quite logical suggestions. I will try. @Martin. But I thought that SMS was a secure way. I am surprised.

Comment: @MahmutSalman what made you think SMS was secure? There is no encryption or authentication mechanism in that communication. A device can send a message to a cell tower stating it is the reciever for a phone number and can collect any SMS data destined for that number. The device can then reply with an error code so the delivery is marked as incomplete and then when the [real] phone contacts another network node the message gets resent, but because the message is open then whoever receives it (as well as any staff on the cell network or infrastructure) will be able to see the message.

Comment: I thought it is secure because inside my web app users must enter their mobile phone numbers. Each number is unique. So I can understand that transactions are made by a real human. And in case of any abnormal activity, I can reach the phone number's information by requesting info from the phone operator(provider). So I can eliminate robotic/scripted activity. @Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a verification table where in this table a number to be verified, verification code, verification status and expiry time are stored.
When a user clicks verify, you match his/her code with that one in your database and if its correct and in the corresponding expiry timeframe, you update the verification status

Comment: Is it logical to hold every user's one-time verification info in the database? Or I can delete that info after a certain amount of time?

Comment: After Verification, you can delete the record